# Distance measure for categorical attributes for k-Nearest Neighbor

Tags: machine-learning, classification, nearest-neighbor, knn, euclidean-distance

For my class project, I am working on the [Kaggle competition - Don't get kicked](https://www.kaggle.com/c/DontGetKicked)

The project is to classify test data as good/bad buy for cars. There are 34 features and the data is highly skewed. I made the following choices:

1. Since the data is highly skewed, out of 73,000 instances, 64,000 instances are bad buy and only 9,000 instances are good buy. Since building a decision tree would overfit the data, I chose to use kNN - K nearest neighbors.
   After trying out kNN, I plan to [try out Perceptron and SVM techniques](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60270/categorizing-transportation-modes-with-k-nearest-neighbor), if kNN doesn't yield good results. Is my understanding about overfitting correct?
2. Since some features are numeric, I can directly use the Euclid distance as a measure, but there are other attributes which are categorical. To aptly use these features, I need to come up with my own distance measure. I read about [Hamming distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance), but I am still unclear on how to merge 2 distance measures so that each feature gets equal weight.
3. Is there a way to find a good approximate for value of k? I understand that this depends a lot on the use-case and varies per problem. But, if I am taking a simple vote from each neighbor, how much should I set the value of k? I'm currently trying out various values, such as 2,3,10 etc.

I researched around and found these links, but these are not specifically helpful -
a) [Metric for nearest neighbor](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72871/metric-for-nearest-neighbor-method), which says that finding out your own distance measure is equivalent to 'kernelizing', but couldn't make much sense from it.
b) [Distance independent approximation of kNN](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/39139/distance-independent-approximation-of-nearest-neighbor-k-nn) talks about R-trees, M-trees etc. which I believe don't apply to my case.
c) [Finding nearest neighbors using Jaccard coeff](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/16078/finding-nearest-neighbors-using-jaccard-distance-for-positive-real-valued-vecto?newreg=9ae97574fe1c4f57ab198e9e3711dc5a)

Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1):

1. Since the data is unbalanced, you should either sample an equal number of good/bad (losing lots of "bad" records), or use an algorithm that can account for this. I think there's an SVM implementation in RapidMiner that does this.
2. You should use Cross-Validation to avoid overfitting. You might be using the term [overfitting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting) incorrectly here though.
3. You should normalize distances so that they have the same weight. By normalize I mean force to be between 0 and 1. To normalize something, subtract the minimum and divide by the range.
4. The way to find the optimal value of K is to try all possible values of K (while cross-validating) and chose the value of K with the highest accuracy. If a "good" value of K is fine, then you can use a genetic algorithm or similar to find it. Or you could try K in steps of say 5 or 10, see which K leads to good accuracy (say it's 55), then try steps of 1 near that "good value" (ie 50,51,52...) but this may not be optimal.

Comment: 1. I can do pruning on the data, but I believe since I'm using kNN, it shouldn't matter if I have chosen my attributes carefully. Is my understanding that kNN can handle skewed data wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the normalizing distance tip. I'll do that right away and look at Cross-validation as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at the exact same problem.

Regarding the choice of k, it's recommended be an odd value to avoid getting "tie votes".

I hope to expand this answer in the future.